# scene to vs scene of

Tags: grammar, prepositions, word-usage

I am a non-native speaker wondering which of the following sentences would read more naturally to a native speaker:

> The market looked like it had been the scene of a mass murder.
>
> The market looked like it had been scene to a mass murder

I'm also unsure about the article before 'scene'. Is it absolutely necessary or could I omit it as seen in the second example (given that I'm okay with an informal tone to my text)?

Comment: The first one is correct.

Comment: Thank you @MaxWilliams. But does that mean that the second one is wrong?

Comment: I'm having trouble deciding on the second one. I'm pretty sure reporters say things like "An apartment on the upper East side last night *was scene to a* gruesome murder." Interested to read what others think.

Comment: Yep, the second one is wrong. It's even more problematic in speech than in writing, because it sounds exactly like "was seen to". Reporters use all kinds of ungrammatical short-cuts in the heat of the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you definitely wanted to use the word *scene*, then your first example is correct and your second incorrect.

You could, however, say

> The market looked like it had been witness to a mass murder.

making sure to leave the article out. To say that the market looked like it had been "the witness of a mass murder" or would be either incorrect or at least very strange—certainly a phrase that would make the reader go, hunh? Using "the witness to a mass murder" would be less problematic, but it would still be strange—in other words, it's not grammatically incorrect; it's just not what people say.